# Compiling SVN Perl bindings on Snow Leopard: tests fail

Tags: mac-osx, svn, testing, osx-snow-leopard

At my work, we have to build our Subversion environment from source since it is deployed on shared applications servers and all dependencies must be contained within the user's home directory. I've developed a script that builds everything (including Apache 2.2.14, SVN 1.6.6, PHP 5.3.1, and MySQL 5.1.41) from source, and it all works flawlessly under 10.5 (Leopard) and 10.4 (Tiger). However, when I build it on 10.6 (Snow Leopard), everything succeeds except for the tests that ship with the SWIG Perl bindings for Subversion. Here's an excerpt from the first part of the epic fail, to conserve space:

```
../../../../../subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/t/0use.............ok    
../../../../../subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/t/1repos...........Directory needs to be empty but is not: Repository creation failed: Could not create top-level directory: '/var/folders/yD/yDpb4DctHjOFN0lC4QHjz++++TI/-Tmp-/svn-perl-test-l7N5wb' exists and is non-empty at ../../../../../subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/t/1repos.t line 18
# cleanup
# Looks like your test died before it could output anything.
../../../../../subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/t/1repos...........dubious
    Test returned status 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
DIED. FAILED tests 1-6
    Failed 6/6 tests, 0.00% okay
```

(All failures have the same root cause, *"Repository creation failed: Could not create top-level directory"*.)

I've tried everything obvious, and checked whether the directory it mentions actually exists before the test runs, and it doesn't. I'm puzzled why this works fine on everything but Snow Leopard. It even appears that the Perl bindings at least partially work, which makes the test failures all the more puzzling. I (and others I work with) would really like the assurance that the bindings actually work when building, so we can use pre/post-commit hooks that utilize the bindings and know they will work.

Solutions to what is causing these failures would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not a clue, but you are not the only person with issues with Perl and Snow Leopard: http://twitter.com/timbray/statuses/6156016213 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279939/how-do-i-fix-symbol-not-found-isprefix-when-compiling-perls-dbdmysql